# Is there a function similar to getspnam() in php?

Tags: php, c

Wondering if a function similar to getspnam in C is there in php also..  
I found a function named posix_getpwnam() in php which almost does the same task. An example from the manual is given below

```
<?php

$userinfo = posix_getpwnam("tom");

print_r($userinfo);
?>
```

with an output as

```
Array
(
    [name]    => tom
    [passwd]  => x
    [uid]     => 10000
    [gid]     => 42
    [gecos]   => "tom,,,"
    [dir]     => "/home/tom"
    [shell]   => "/bin/bash"
)
```

As you can see it is giving the details from  the file /etc/passwd, while I need them from the /etc/shadow file.   
   While in C, this can be easily done by using getspnam("tom") and the data can be dereferenced from a predefined structure.

So how can we do that using php??